# How to use custom setter in Kotlin class constructor body

Tags: kotlin

I couldn't find a better title for describing how can I avoid code duplication (require expressions) in this Kotlin class:

```
class Person(email: String) {
    var email: String = email
        set(value) {
            require(value.trim().isNotEmpty(), { "The email cannot be blank" })
            field = value
        }

    init {
        require(email.trim().isNotEmpty(), { "The email cannot be blank" })
    }
}
```

In java, I would have a setter with the name validation and then I would call it from the constructor.

What is the idiomatic way of doing that in Kotlin ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a delegate. There's the observable() delegate that already exists.

```
class Person(initialEmail: String) { // No "var" any more.
    var email: String by Delegates.observable("") {
    _, _, newValue ->
        // This code is called every time the property is set.
        require(newValue.trim().isNotEmpty(), { "The email cannot be blank" })
    }

    init {
        // Set the property at construct time, to invoke the delegate.
        email = initialEmail
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the [`Delegates.observable(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html) delegate can be enough if the lambda should throw an exception on a bad value.

Comment: Absolutely. I'd prefer vetoable() and no `require`, myself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Paul. I tried what you have suggested using Delegates but I found that it only works when the property changes its value and not when instantiating a new object.
Also I don't think that it would be "idiomatic" to throw an exception from a method that should return true or false based on whether the field has changed or not.

Comment: You're right, I must have had debug code that made it work while I was testing it. I need to use init. However, it isn't a major change. Onesec..

Comment: The new code makes `vetoable` useless now. Switched to `observable`. Thanks @hotkey.

Comment: Yes, now it works Paul. I must admit that even though we got around the problem of code duplication, it becomes a little bit verbose and complex taking into account that in my real case scenario, I would have multiple entities with more than one property that would need some sort of validation.

Comment: Usually, validation doesn't happen this way. Your pattern is "record the data then check it"; a more common pattern is "check the data then record it". That is: if the email is empty, then don't create the object.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it just like in java. You just have to remove the primary constructor and make a secondary constructor instead. You will have to do the assignment manually though, like in java. So it would look like this:

```
class Person {
    constructor(email: String) {
        this.email = email
    }

    var email: String
        set(value) {
            require(value.trim().isNotEmpty(), { "The email cannot be blank" })
            field = value
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the member outside of the constructor, and invoke the setter from the init block:

```
class Person(initialEmail: String) { // This is just the constructor parameter.
    var email: String = "" // This is the member declaration which calls the custom setter.
        set(value) {          // This is the custom setter.
            require(value.trim().isNotEmpty(), { "The email cannot be blank" })
            field = value
        }

    init {
        // Set the property at construct time, to invoke the custom setter.
        email = initialEmail
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not prevent me from doing `Person("")`

Comment: Fixed, as per the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative way, to use companion object and create object there, it's kind like the constructor and meets your requirement in a different way.

```
data class Target(
        val date: LocalDate,
        val id: Long,
        val stringId: String,
) {
    companion object {
        fun create(date: LocalDate, id: Long, stringId: String?,): Target{
            val nonNullStringId= if (stringId.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else stringId
            return Target(date, id, nonNullStringId)
        }
    }
}
```